How do I identify different accelerations on rotational rigid body dynamics?

So consider the image above (A cord passing over a pulley that is carrying a mass of $M_1$ at one end and wrapped around a cylinder of mass $M_2$ on a plane at the other end).
Apparently I was told that the acceleration of both $M_1$ and $M_2$ is different, but wasn't explained how it's different and what the actual ratio is. Explaining the overall concept would be very helpful, or even a guidance of proving it would be better. Thanks in advance!

"the acceleration is different" acceleration of what? you have a linear movement of M1, rolling so rotation  on M2 and rotation of the rotation of the small roll., What are your steps, what  did you try? it seems to be homework, which is not answered here.

@trula I was asking about the concept, not answers to a homework question. The photo was even a random one I found on the internet that correlates most to the question I'd like to ask.

from  the free body diagram, write the equations of motion , and see why the acceleration $~a_{M_1}~$ is different to the acceleration $~a_{M_2}$

You still do not tell of which acceleration you are talking- F=M1*g gives the torque to move M2, so the Center of mass of M2 has of cause a different a from M1. you need the moment of inertia of the cylinder m2 to find the acceleration .

How to solve
1) create a the Free Body diagram
2) Newton Euler equations of motion
$$M_1\,a_1=-T+...\\
M_2\,a_2=+T+...\\
I_2\,\alpha=T\,r+...$$
where $~T~$ is the constraint force
3) Kinematic constraint equation
the distribution matrix of the constraint force $~T~$ is
$$ \mathbf  C_T=\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 \\
  1 \\
  r \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
form here the kinematic constraint equation :
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   a_1 & a_2 & \alpha \\
 \end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 \\
  1 \\
  r \\
\end{bmatrix}\,=0$$
you obtain 4 equations (Newton Euler + Kinematic ) for the 4 unknowns $~a_1~,a_2~,\alpha~,T~$
